# What design should I use for a desk that is only around 1' deep?

Tags: furniture, design, desk

I have a small apartment. I have an empty wall space that is approximately 1 foot 'deep' as it butts up to what I would call a "room divider" wall.

I want to use this space for an office desk. I need to include my laptop, a 27" monitor, a keyboard, a laser printer, and room beneath to push in my rolling chair when not in use.

I'd prefer to limit the width of this desk to no longer than 4'.

Should I build (or possibly find) a simple "skinny" table that is short enough to be used as a desk? Are there other designs or pieces of furniture that are better suited for this type of space and usage?

I'm hoping that there are similar furniture designs used historically or for other purposes that might be well applied to this situation.

Comment: Would this answer qualify if I said 'What designs can I use..."? I understand that 'should' is subjective; I'm just not sure how to properly phrase the question. Obviously any problem can have multiple solutions. Is that against the rules here on `diy`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A "standing desk" would fit such a space, and be very easy to install:

[image: standing desk, wall mount]